# How to color ggplot points above and below a regression line in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, regression

I have a dataset and plot like like below:

```
rowid <- (1:100)
intercept <- (200:299)
df <- data.frame(rowid, intercept)

ggplot(df, aes(x=rowid, y=intercept, color=intercept)) + geom_point() 
+ scale_colour_gradient2(low="red", high="darkgreen", mid = "yellow", midpoint = 250) 
+ geom_smooth(method='lm', color = 'black')
```

My dataset and plot have way more data so it looks like:
[image: r plot]

**Question:**

How do I get the points above the regression line to be a certain color (green), points below the regression line to be a certain color (red), and all other points a certain color (yellow)?

On top of that (if possible), I would like to add another column label `Grade` that shows the above the regression line points listed as "A", all other points as "C", and below the regression line listed as "F".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a first example (without the possibility of a point to lie directly ON the regression line): Compute the fitted value for every x-value, fitting a linear model before the actual plotting. After that you can simply bind a boolean column to your data frame, specifying if the predicted value is smaller or larger than the true y.

```
library(ggplot2)

rowid <- (1:1000)
intercept <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)*rowid+1:1000
mod <- lm(intercept ~ rowid)
fitted <- mod$fitted.values
smaller <- intercept < fitted
df <- data.frame(rowid, intercept, smaller)


ggplot(df, aes(x=rowid, y=intercept, color=as.factor(smaller))) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method='lm', color = 'black')+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "yellow"))
```

[image]

Having read the last sentence of your post only now, an approach to introduce a three leveled factor column with the levels "A", "F" and "C" and plotting them accordingly afterwards. I introduced 200 points, where fitted value and true y are equal:

```
library(ggplot2)

rowid <- (1:1000)
intercept <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)*rowid+1:1000
mod <- lm(intercept ~ rowid)
fitted <- mod$fitted.values
#demonstration: add some points, where fitted value equals the true value
sample_points <- sample(1:1000, 200, replace = FALSE)

intercept[sample_points] <- fitted[sample_points]

#construct three level factor, with a chain of ifelse:
grade <- as.factor(ifelse(intercept < fitted, "F", ifelse(intercept == fitted, "C", "A")))
df <- data.frame(rowid, intercept, grade)

ggplot(df, aes(x=rowid, y=intercept, color=grade)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method='lm', color = 'black')+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "yellow", "red"))
```

Comment: Is it possible to save all points above the regression line in a new data frame?

Comment: Well, obviously you  can filter according to the boolean `smaller` which we've created before and save the results to separate dataframes. `df_smaller <- df[smaller, ]` and
`df_bigger <- df[!smaller, ]` .

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to re-implement what `geom_smooth()` is doing with something like

```r
m = lm(intercept~rowid, data=df) # note that format is y~x
```

Which will give you slope and intercept under `m$coefficients`. You can check this with

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=rowid, y=intercept, color=intercept)) + geom_point() +
    scale_colour_gradient2(low="red", high="darkgreen", mid = "yellow", midpoint = 250) +
    # geom_smooth(method='lm', color = 'black') + 
    geom_abline(slope = m$coefficients[2], intercept = m$coefficients[1])
```

which replaces the `geom_smooth()` line

You can then create a new column in `df` that tells if you are above/below the line or just use `m$residuals`. Example of the former option would be something like

```r
df = cbind(df, up_down = if_else(
    df$intercept > df$row_id*m$coefficients[2]+m$coefficients[1],
    "above", 
    "below")
) # pseudocode
```