# Creating data table of points above/below abline in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table, regression, panel-data

Is it possible to identify data points above a `geom_abline` in ggplot, and to create a new data table separating these data points using `data.table`?

I have a panel dataset with 150 unique `ID`'s, and have fit a fixed effects model using plm(). Here is a sample of the dataset:

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3),
                   year = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3),
                   progenyMean = c(90,78,92,69,86,73,82,85,91),
                   damMean = c(89,89,72,98,95,92,94,87,89)

ID, year, progenyMean, damMean
1, 1, 70, 69
1, 2, 68, 69
1, 3, 72, 72
1, 4, 69, 68
2, 1, 76, 75
2, 2, 73, 80
3, 1, 72, 74
3, 2, 75, 67
3, 3, 71, 69

# Fixed Effects Model in plm
fixed <- plm(progenyMean ~ damMean, data, model= "within", index = c("ID","year"))
```

I have plotted the response `progenyMean` vs `damMean` using the following code:

```
plotFunction <- function(aggData, year){
  
  ggplot(aggData, aes(x=damMeanCentered, y=progenyMean3Y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_abline(slope=fixed$coefficients, intercept=71.09, colour='dodgerblue1', size=1)
# The intercept 71.09 was calculated using the mean of fixef(fixed)
  
}

plotFunction(data, '(2005 - 2012)')
```

[image]

Is it possible to identify the points above/below the `geom_abline` in ggplot and create a new data table separating these data points using `data.table`?

Comment: If you already have the equation for your line, it's not a ggplot or data.table operation so much as doing the algebra of whether each point is greater or less than the predicted y-value at its x-value

Comment: For example https://stackoverflow.com/q/62581291/5325862, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12799457/5325862

Comment: @camille I attempted this method in the post you linked, however it doesn't seem to work (possibly because I'm working with panel data)

Comment: I don't see why that would change things (I could be missing something). You have the equation of a line (y = mx + b, filling in whatever your slope and y-intercept are). You have x-values (dam quality), and you have observed y-values (progeny quality). Use that equation to get each x-value's predicted y-value, then check if y_observed > y_predicted

Comment: Why does your intercept say it's 71.09 but in the graph it looks like it is closer to 58?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor The variable on the x-axis has been centered, so the x-axis value 0 is where the intercept hits 71.09

Comment: @codemachino ahhh I spaced it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear where the intercept came from, but nevertheless the trick is
add a predict to your dataset using the `regression model` (in your case *fixed*). Then filter out actual values that are higher than the predict.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
mutate(predict = predict(fixed, newdata = data)) %>%
filter(progenyMean > predict)
```

Comment: This seems to produce an error message: Problem with `mutate()` column `predict`.
ℹ `predict = predict(fixed, newdata = period1_above)`.
x non-conformable arguments

Comment: Is it possible to do this using `data.table` instead of `dplyr` ?

Comment: Refresh data with your first line of code before using:

Answer (score 1):

First make the predictions

```
data[,newpredict:=predict(fixed, newdata=data)]
```

It's not clear what you want the new `data.table` to look like but you'd get the values above predictions by doing

```
data[progencyMean>newpredict]
```

For below, you'd obviously just change the `>` to `<`.